# Magento review for logged in customer on one product

Tags: php, magento

I have a loop that shows all products that a customer has ordered, within that loop I want to pull out if the customer has rated that one product what rating they have given it. I think the problem is I need to use review/summary to display the rating?

```
$productsreviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getProductCollection()->addCustomerFilter(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())->setDateOrder();
    foreach ($productsreviews as $productsreview)
            {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productsreview->getData('entity_pk_value')); 
            }

    echo $product->getRating();
```

EDIT:Full Code

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

/* Get the customer data */
$customer       = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/* Get the customer's email address */
$customer_email = $customer->getEmail();
$customer_id = $customer->getId();

}

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', array(
'like' => $customer_email
 ));



$uniuqProductSkus = array();

foreach ($collection as $order) { 

    $order_id = $order->getId(); 
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); 
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 
        foreach ($ordered_items as $item) 
        { 
        if (in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $uniuqProductSkus)) { 
        continue; 
        } else { 
            array_push($uniuqProductSkus, $item->getProduct()->getSku()); 

            $_product                 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $product_small_image_path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200);
            $product_thumbnail_path   = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150);
            $summaryData              = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->load($item->getProductId());


            echo "<li>";

            echo "<div class='previous-name'><p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
            echo $item->getName() . "</a></p></div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-image'><a href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
            echo "<img src='" . $product_small_image_path . "' />";
            echo "</a></div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-rating'>";
            echo "<p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "#product_tabs_review_tabbed'>Review this beer now</a></p>";

            echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . '% Would buy again <br/>';

            echo "<div class='rating-box' style='float:left;'>";
            echo "<div class='rating' style='width:" . $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . "%'></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='previous-clear'></div></div>";



            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

review/summary will display the aggregated data. IIRC there's no method to pull out single review along with rating using the review model. This should give you the review object with associated rating:

```
        $cReviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection()
                    ->addStoreFilter($oProduct->getStoreId())
                    ->addRateVotes()
                    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                    ->addEntityFilter('product', $oProduct->getId())
                    ->setDateOrder()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $yourCustomerId);
$cReviews->getSelect()->limit(1);
$oReview = $cReviews->getFirstItem();
```

Then you will have to calculate rating average for the single review:

```
if ( ($cRatings = $oReview->getRatingVotes()) && count($cRatings) ) {
            $rAverage = array_sum($cRatings->getColumnValues('value')) / count($cRatings);
            }
```

Comment: I basically just need to get this block review/customer/view.phtml into my custom page that I have pasted in my question